# No column is created for one to one mapping hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two tables schema

1. employee
2. address

Their is one to one mapping between employee and address in address hbm.xml

```
<one-to-one name="employee" class="packageName.Employee" constrained="true"></one-to-one>
```

in address pojo file Employee employee

After table creation there is no column created for employee_id in address table
Why so?

Comment: Where is the mapping ?

Comment: @newbuddy why do you think that the column should be generated automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `many-to-one` ,rather than one to one

```
<many-to-one name="employee"
        class="packageName.Employee" cascade="refresh"
        column="employee_id" not-null="true"></many-to-one>
```

Comment: Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "one-to-one".